# Handbrake: 'Your destination directory is low on diskspace'

Tags: video, disk-space, handbrake

In Handbrake v1.2.2 (2019022300) on a Windows 10 laptop I get the following error when the destination directory is set to my C: drive which has 100Gb+ of free space: "Your destination directory is low on diskspace. Please free up some disk space on your destination drive. Alternatively you can change the level at which this alert triggers in Options."

1. How do I get completely rid of this error?
2. 'Options' does not seem to have an option to change when this alert triggers. Where, exactly, is this setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't (yet) seen this error, but you can change the setting in the `Preferences -> Advanced` tab:

[image: screenshot handbrake preferences]

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution. This drove me crazy because it just started happening for no reason and I have 1TB free on my hard drive. Do what they say above except on the newest version (1.3.3) it's Preferences > Advanced > Pause queue if disk is lower than:

Put the setting on   .5

It didn't work on the first try but then I quit out of the program and reopened it and then it worked. It's been working fine ever since.